# How to mark method parameter as retained by receiver

Tags: objective-c, clang, automatic-ref-counting

Consider this object `Widget`

```
typedef void (^Completion)(BOOL result);

@interface Widget ()

@property (nonatomic,strong) Completion retainedBlock;

@end

@implementation Widget

-(void)doStuff:(Completion)block {

    NSLog(@"stuff done , caller will still release");
    block(YES);
}

-(void)doRetainingStuff:(__strong Completion)block {

    NSLog(@"stuff done - mwah hah i have retained you! NO releasing!");

    self.retainedBlock = block;
    self.retainedBlock(YES);


}

@end
```

How do i mark the parameter in `-(void)doRetainingStuff:(__strong Completion)block` as retained by the receiver. ( using `__strong` doesnt do it )

If the passed in block contains a reference to `self` the caller will be retained and I get a retain cycle.

I want clang to tell me that I have a retain cycle happening in either deep or shallow mode.

Yes I know can weak'ify at the calling side but I want to formalise the contract so that my compiler tells when I'm being dumb.

So that when I do this...

```
- (IBAction)releasableCall:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"i will still release");
    [self.widget doStuff:^(BOOL result) {
        [self zap];
    }];

}


- (IBAction)nonReleaseableCall:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"i will not release after this");
    [self.widget doRetainingStuff:^(BOOL result) {
        [self zap];
    }];

}


-(void)zap {

    NSLog(@"foo");

}
```

I don't have to go leak hunting manually.